Hypersphere of Fractal Dimensions
Is the concept of a fractal dimension when applied to questions like a fractal dimension hypersphere volume nonsense?
For example: Can a 4.5 dimensional hypersphere exist and have a 4.5D volume.  And if so does just using the continuous gamma function formula for hypersphere's actually work.
This is regarding a video by math and science influencer Tibees recent video "Riding a train until I understand hyperspheres" at 7min30sec she is reading Clifford Pickover's book "Surfing Through Hyperspace".
There's a challenge to the reader to find the volume of a hypersphere of 4.5 Dimensions using the gamma function.
https://youtu.be/LA4RRdfvXIo?si=isiSmAS7yxsQN7J-&t=450
I'm not sure a Hausdorff "dimension" that fractals are measured with can be converted into a Euclidian dimension (or Lebesgue measure) just by abusing the shared use of the term Dimension and the Gamma function to get continuous factorials.  I'm confident Pickover's book is treating it as an exercise for Gamma functions not a proper geometry problem - and that poor Tibees is wasting her time.
A proper geometry problem in my mind would be some hypothetical sphere like fractal with Hausdorff dimension 4.5 that a volume bound could be calculated for with contour curves.
The volume formula of a hypersphere can be found here.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball
Sorry I'm trying to make this not seem like multiple questions - the following is merely meant to be opportunities where I could be wrong that an advanced answer could potentially correct me with to demonstrate it is NOT nonsense.

I don't think fractional Euclidian spaces can exist.
I don't think even if they did the definition of an n-sphere could be extended to it.
I don't think the n-sphere volume formula using the gamma function would work if applied to a fractal sphere. Or a sphere in a fractional dimension.
Does the n-sphere gamma function volume formula have any geometrical meaning for fractional dimensions.

Thank you.

Did you consider reading a book about fractals, Hausdorff dimension and Hausdorff measure instead of watching YouTube videos?

Why is the word dimension surrounded by " "?

@MoisheKohan I know enough that I think it is wrong to conflate the subjects, but I'm not authoritative enough to explain that to Clifford Pickover.
